# Cannot Ubuntu desktop edition perform as Ubuntu Server Edition?

Tags: 14.04, networking, server, upgrade, software-recommendation

I found two separate OS **Ubuntu Desktop Edition** (*like Ubuntu 14.04 LTS which I am using* )  and **Ubuntu Server Edition** OS available. Server Edition is used to do the performance for hosting a Ubuntu server and other web stuffs.
But **is it necessary to shift to the server edition from the desktop edition**?
 or
 **can we do our job of server related tasks with the Desktop edition**?
 *If possible where do I begin from?*

Answer (score 2):

You can do everything you need from the desktop edition, provided you install the needed software.

More importantly, server actually *removes* some features from desktop edition, which don't make particularly much sense for an enterprise server installation, but you might want available for your purposes. So you might prefer to stay with Ubuntu Desktop, or use some Ubuntu derivative with lighter requirements, especially in GUI department, like xubuntu or lubuntu.